# Server resources needed to run Geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm running Geth on an AWS [micro](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) server with 1GB of RAM of 50GB of storage (EBS). If I run it with the `--fast` flag on, it crashes after a couple of minutes because it runs out of memory. If I run it normal mode with `--rpc` on, any requests to the Geth client are processed with delays.

What are the RAM / CPU requirements so I can run it with the `--fast` flag on and so that it can handle a couple of `rpc` calls a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running `geth` on 2 DNS load balanced "Linode 4GB" servers costing USD 20 / month each. The specs are:

- 4GB RAM
- 2 CPU Cores
- 48 GB SSD Storage
- 3TB Transfer Out
- 40 Gbps Network In
- 1,000 Mbps Network Out

I run `geth` alongside a Java application serving the web pages for https://cryptoderivatives.market/ .

I have had a few instances where `geth` is terminated by the operating system due to running out of memory. But I have set up the systemd services so that `geth` automatically restarts. You can find my systemd setup at https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkysCheatsheet/wiki/Linux .

As the disk space is not sufficient to hold the full archive node, I periodically remove the blockchain data and `--fast` sync .

The Digital Ocean service with similar specs works as well.

The network transfers of 3TB is more than sufficient to sync the blockchain with the Ethereum network.

Comment: How much disk space does the Ethereum Mainnet need?

Comment: When you first fast sync, your Mainnet chaindata will be around 13Gb. Compared to a full archive node chaindata of 139Gb.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running `geth --fast` on a $20 Digital Ocean VPS with 2GB of RAM, and it stays up most of the time. Even then it still falls over occasionally, so it still needs a systemd script or whatever to start it back up.

Comment: Thanks. When it crashes, does it affect the integrity of the blockchain data or does it always re write from where it left off?

Comment: Seems to pick up fine as far as I can tell.